# Add font to bootstrap sub-theme

Tags: 8, theming

I use drupal 8, and [Bootstrap theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap).

I created a sub-theme.

I would like added one font that I downloaded, to use it in my sub-theme.

I read contradictory things to realize it. For example that it was enough to create a folder "font" in its sub-theme, and add the font in it, then add it in `mytheme.libraries.yml`, or that it was necessary to place this font in the folder `vendor/` . I am a little lost.

How can it be done?

Comment: Please add more information about what the contradictory things were and what you have tried.

Comment: I read for example that it was enough to create a folder "font" in his sub-theme, and add the font in it, then add it in mytheme.libraries.yml, or that it was necessary to place this font in the folder vendor/ . I am a little lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed [this guide on Google Fonts](https://www.kinetasystems.com/blog/adding-google-fonts-to-a-drupal-8-theme) to get it to work with my downloaded font. In your case that would be editing your info file to declare that you have fonts assets:

```
name: Subboot
description: Bootstrap Subtheme
type: theme
base theme: bootstrap
core: 8.x
libraries:
  - subboot/fonts
```

then edit the libraries.yml in your subtheme, ex. subboot.libraries.yml to add in the following:

```
fonts:
  css:
    theme:
      //your.domain.com/path/to/font {}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me, I put the font file in woff format at fonts directory of my subtheme. Do I have to define it or specify it anywhere else?
my library declaration is like this: `fonts:
  css:
    theme:
      //fonts {}`